# I cant install scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, scrapy

´ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test
copying src\twisted\internet\test\test_win32serialport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test
copying src\twisted\internet\test_posixifaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test
copying src\twisted\internet\test_win32ifaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test
copying src\twisted\internet\test_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\logger\test
copying src\twisted\logger\test\test_buffer.py -> 3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\component.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\ijabber.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\jid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\jstrports.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\sasl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\sasl_mechanisms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\xmlstream.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber\xmpp_stringprep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
copying src\twisted\words\protocols\jabber_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\protocols\jabber
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted_threads\test
copying src\twisted_threads\test\test_convenience.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted_threads\test
copying src\twisted_threads\test\test_memory.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted_threads\test
copying src\twisted_threads\test\test_team.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted_threads\test
copying src\twisted_threads\test\test_threadworker.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted_threads\test
copying src\twisted_threads\test_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted_threads\test
running egg_info
writing src\Twisted.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\Twisted.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to src\Twisted.egg-info\entry_points.txt
writing requirements to src\Twisted.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to src\Twisted.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src\Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.misc' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bugfix' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.doc' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.feature' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.removal' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'NEWS' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'README' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'newsfragments' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\twisted\topfiles\CREDITS'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\twisted\topfiles\ChangeLog.Old'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'pyproject.toml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveralls.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.circleci'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.circleci'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bin'
no previously-included directories found matching 'admin'
no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'docs\historic\2003'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs\historic\2003'
writing manifest file 'src\Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
copying src\twisted\python\twisted-completion.zsh -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python_pydoctortemplates
copying src\twisted\python_pydoctortemplates\common.html -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python_pydoctortemplates
copying src\twisted\python_pydoctortemplates\index.html -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python_pydoctortemplates
copying src\twisted\python_pydoctortemplates\summary.html -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python_pydoctortemplates
copying src\twisted\test\cert.pem.no_trailing_newline -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\test
copying src\twisted\test\key.pem.no_trailing_newline -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\test
copying src\twisted\test\server.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\test
copying src\twisted\test\test_defer.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\test
copying src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\notes.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\iocpreactor
copying src\twisted\internet\test_awaittests.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test
copying src\twisted\internet\test_yieldfromtests.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\chain.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\not-a-certificate -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing1.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2-duplicate.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
copying src\twisted\mail\test\rfc822.message -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\mail\test
copying src\twisted\python\test_deprecatetests.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\python\test
copying src\twisted\trial\test_assertiontests.py.3only -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\trial\test
copying src\twisted\words\im\instancemessenger.glade -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\im
copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpathparser.g -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\words\xish
running build_ext
building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted\test
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\users\josé antonio\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\josé antonio\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
raiser.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\josé antonio\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\josé antonio\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64 /EXPORT:PyInit_raiser build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\twisted\test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.lib
Creando biblioteca build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.lib y objeto build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp39-win_amd64.exp
Generando código
Generación de código finalizada
building 'twisted.internet.iocpreactor.iocpsupport' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted\internet
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\iocpsupport
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\users\josé antonio\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\josé antonio\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.obj
iocpsupport.c
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2229): warning C4047: '=': '__pyx_t_11iocpsupport_HANDLE' es distinto en los niveles de direccionamiento indirecto de 'HANDLE'
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4022: 'CreateIoCompletionPort': no coincide el puntero para el parámetro real 1
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4022: 'CreateIoCompletionPort': no coincide el puntero para el parámetro real 2
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2377): warning C4047: '=': '__pyx_t_11iocpsupport_HANDLE' es distinto en los niveles de direccionamiento indirecto de 'HANDLE'
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2492): warning C4022: 'GetQueuedCompletionStatus': no coincide el puntero para el parámetro real 1
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2838): warning C4022: 'PostQueuedCompletionStatus': no coincide el puntero para el parámetro real 1
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(2949): warning C4022: 'CloseHandle': no coincide el puntero para el parámetro real 1
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(3292): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(4932): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(5149): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(5786): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6146): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6164): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6182): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsWriteBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(6509): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(7614): error C2039: "tp_print": no es un miembro de "_typeobject"
c:\users\josé antonio\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: vea la declaración de '_typeobject'
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8421): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
src/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c(8437): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\josé antonio\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\José Antonio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i3qtohxg\twisted_0a83064f141b4317b3c2f91b7969f2d7\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\José Antonio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i3qtohxg\twisted_0a83064f141b4317b3c2f91b7969f2d7\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\José Antonio\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-49mgh4lu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\josé antonio\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.´

*This is my first time using scrapy and I cant even install it, please help me!!*

Comment: Can you elaborate on the details on how you tried to install it? I would assure you are using windows 10 x64. Did you use *conda* or *virtualenv* to create a virtual environment?

Comment: i just opened my command prompt and typed pip install scrapy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know what's exactly going on in your computer. But here is a method that works on my machine.

1. Install Anaconda (https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads)
2. Open Anaconda Prompt and create a virtual environment, which is always a good practice to have one. This will help your base environment safe and untouched. Suppose we are going to create a virtual environment named scraping with Python=3.8 (more details at https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). Then you can just run

```sh
conda create -n scraping python=3.8
```

3. Activate your virtual environment and install your package.

```sh
conda activate scraping
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
# an alternative way is to run
# pip install Scrapy
```

More instructions can be found at https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html.

Please let me know if you have any questions about the method above.
Cheers!